# Dynamic growing of axis text in a bar chart in D3 JS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, charts

I've got an SVG object representing a bar chart. For the moment, I have used css classes to specify the text size for the y axis:

```
<style>
            .axis path,
            .axis line {
                stroke: black;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .axis text {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
</style>
```

Is there a way to make the text on the axis change dynamically with the same % as the svg object is resized? And also for the width of the line axis as well?

At the moment if I try to resize the svg by making it smaller, the text size doesn't change and it overlaps.

Thanks

Comment: It should always do that. It's actually quite hard to make it not work like that :-)

Comment: It doesn't because I've tried resizing the svg and as it gets smaller the text overlaps.

Comment: sounds like the svg isn't resizing. Perhaps you should add that to the question.